# Searching a map and retrieving key if matching -angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Angular-JS
Searching a map and retrieving key if matching with the user given input key

my map luks like this

var myMap=
    {
    k:1000,
    l:100000,
    m:1000000,
    c:10000000
    };
If user input is "l" , i want to search the map and retrieve l along with value "100000"
and do some further operation

Comment: Try var key = 'l'; var value = myMap[key];

Comment: i dont wish to set my key as "l" and then get value. the input is dynamic. user can give any value like k,l,m,c etc

Comment: That was an example. As myMap is an object (aka associative array, aka hash) you can access a value using [] operator.

Comment: Have added an answer so that I can show a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

As myMap is an object (aka associative array, aka hash) you can access a value using the 
[] operator.

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.myMap = { k:1000, l:100000, m:1000000, c:10000000 };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='myMapKey' />
  <p>myMap value = {{myMap[myMapKey]}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend the [answer from Gruff Bunny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26906316), you can also do the following to search for the key-value pair and do your calculation inside the controller and get the result as an output.

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.myMap = { k:1000, l:100000, m:1000000, c:10000000 };
  $scope.chkIt = function(myIns){
    var myVal = $scope.myMap[myIns];
    if(myVal){
      //do your calculation here
      $scope.myResult = 'Calculation Done | Key: '+myIns+' | Value: '+myVal;
    }else{
      $scope.myResult = 'No Match for key: '+myIns;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
  <input type='text' ng-change="chkIt(myMapKey)" ng-model='myMapKey' />
  <p>myMap value = {{myResult}}</p>
</div>
```